# How can i get all list items with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-ide

i am new with Selenium and try to get all items in list. 
The code is:

```
<div id="books">
  <ul>
    <li>Aw</li>
    <li>Ax</li>
    <li>Ay</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get all items and check all of them starts with "A"

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get all the items, we can use 'findElements' method like below:

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='books']/ul/li"));
```

Here `items` is a `List` containing the desired elements (i.e. all `<li>` elements).

We can then iterate through this list, and check if the text of these items starts with 'A':

```
for(WebElement e: items)
{
    System.out.print(e.getText());
    if(e.getText().startsWith("A"))
    {
        System.out.println("  ==> starts with 'A'");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("  ==> does NOT start with 'A'");
    }
}
```

Comment: glad, this was helpful !